# Factory Method C++

Tags: c++11, design-patterns, factory-method

I'm a begginer in C++ and I was trying to solve this implementacion of the factory method, where I'm trying to look for the implementation with the funcion ***make object*** below is:

1. Retrive the return type in order to provide access to 
   the created object in the **class Object** below.
2. Create two objects(**Object2** and **Object3**) for the given *id*
3. Trying to be thread safe.

I'm working on the following code:

```
enum ObjectType {
    FO_Object2, FO_Object3
};

class Object {
    int ID;
public:
    Object(int id) : ID(id) {}
    Object(const Object&) = delete;

    virtual void printObject() = 0;
    static Object* make_object(int id);
};

class Object2: public Object
{
public:
    void printObject() {
        std::cout << "ID = 2" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Object3 : public Object
{
public:
    void printObject() {
        std::cout << "ID = 3" << std::endl;
    }
};

//Factory Method to create objects
Object* Object::make_object(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case FO_Object2: return new Object2();
        case FO_Object3: return new Object3();
        default:
            return NULL;
    }
}

class object_factory
{
public:
    object_factory()
    {
        ObjectType id = FO_Object3;
        pObject = Object::make_object(id);
    }
    ~object_factory()
    {
        if (pObject) {
            delete[] pObject;
            pObject = NULL;
        }
    }
    Object* getFactory() {
        return pObject;
    }
private:
    Object* pObject;
};

int main()
{
    object_factory* pFactory = new object_factory();
    Object* pObject = pFactory->getFactory();
    pObject->printObject();

    return 0;
}
```

But unfortunately in my Error list infors me that i have the following Errors:

E1790 --> the default constructor of "Object2" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function.

E1790 --> the default constructor of "Object3" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function.

C2280 --> 'Object2::Object2(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Anyone can help me with this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am struggling that you mix int and ObjectType all around. Why delete[] pObject; if pObject is only a pointer and not an array? And how should objects be created if there is no call to base constructor and base class has no default constructor. And why you have a factory method in you object base class and not in the factory... all a bit strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a corrected sample (as far as I understood what you want to achieved). See code comments clarifying why stuff where changed. A lot more would be needed to make the core more robust (eg using ObjectType inside the base class)

```
#include <iostream>

enum ObjectType {
    FO_Object2 = 2,
   FO_Object3 = 3
};

class Object {
public:
    int ID; // ID must be public so that inherited class can access it. Otherwise create getter for ID
    Object(int id) : ID(id) {};
    Object(const Object&) = delete;

    virtual void printObject() = 0;
    static Object* make_object(int id);
};

class Object2: public Object
{
public:
    Object2():Object(2) {}; // specifically instanciate a base class whose id is 2
    void printObject() {
        std::cout << "ID = "<< ID << std::endl;
    }
};

class Object3 : public Object
{

public:
    Object3():Object(3) {}; // specifically instanciate a base class whose id is 3
    void printObject() {
        std::cout << "ID = "<< ID << std::endl;
    }
};

//Factory Method to create objects
Object* Object::make_object(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case FO_Object2: return new Object2();
        case FO_Object3: return new Object3();
        default:
            return NULL;
    }
}

class object_factory
{
public:
    object_factory()
    {
        ObjectType id = FO_Object3;
        pObject = Object::make_object(id);
    }
    ~object_factory()
    {
        if (pObject) {
            delete[] pObject;
            pObject = NULL;
        }
    }
    Object* getFactory() {
        return pObject;
    }
private:
    Object* pObject;
};

int main()
{
    object_factory* pFactory = new object_factory();
    Object* pObject = pFactory->getFactory();
    pObject->printObject();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you hide the default constructor of the derived classes from everyone but the factory?

Comment: You can declare a constructor as private and have the factory method as a friend of the class. This way only the factory can instantiate the object.